# c# webbrowser | pushed realtime quotes

Tags: c#, browser, quotes, real-time, stock

I am programmer and share trader.

**Before**
I have written a day trading application. Until last week it was possible to fetch realtime quotes from http://aktien.boerse.de/aktien_startseite.php?view=2&order=name%20asc&liste=prime&page=0 . Every time the site was surfed the quotes had changed. The HTML contents could then be decoded with regular expressions (regex).

**Problem**
They have stopped this service by today. Now the quotes are *not* realtime when surfing on the page. The only way to get stock quotes now is to use pushed quotes "Push starten"-Button.
However I do not know how to basically fetch them in C#.
When I create a webbrowser element the only way which I know to get the push quotes out of it is to give the webbrowser element the focus send key ctrl+A and ctrl+C and insert the data some where for decoding. This is not desired since the control is moved away from the user and in case some other control is clicked during the process this may result in unexpected behaviour.

**Question**
So is there a proper way to decode push stock quotes in C#?

Comment: Maybe they know about your little application :)

Comment: you may not be the only one doing this, or people complained about having to refresh the page to see new quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can access the DOM directly through the web browser control - for example to click the button you can use the following (where the browser control is called _browser):

```
HtmlDocument doc = _browser.Document;
HtmlElement el;
el = doc.GetElementById(ButtonName);
el.InvokeMember("click");
```

You can then access the broser DOM at intervals (using `_browser.Document`) and parse using regular expressions the same way as you were previously.  A neater way may be to use XPath to extract the table and individual stock quotes